# Split and parse string into integers

Tags: java, string, split

I am a newbie to JAVA and have a string

```
2015-04-01 01:00:00
```

(It is a string and not a timestamp).
I want to have the string to be splitted into seperate integers.That means I will have 6 integers which are 2015,04,01,01,00,00.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Regular expressions will make you happy

Comment: `s.split("\\W+")` - the solution is in the duped question body. You may also split on non-digit chunks: `s.split("\\D+")`

Comment: `List<Integer> ints = Stream.of("2015-04-01 01:00:00".split("\\D+")).map(Integer::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: just use regex to group integers numbers